# asp.net mvc authorization problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, controller, authorization, security-roles

I am trying to add authorization to my controllers and it's not working...

I am not sure where to look in my program, but adding the

```
[Authorize]
```

filter in my controller is not working, let alone anything like

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
```

I have been able to get this working in the default application that is provided when creating a new MVC project (i.e., I am able to make the "about" tab redirect to the login screen if I'm not logged in), so I assume I have mucked things up along the way as I've built my app.  Does anyone know where I should be looking to fix this?  I have users and they have roles; I'm using the ASP.net schema that is auto-created;  I've examined my web.config file up and down and although I'm pretty new to this, nothing seems to be out of place. I have no clue why my authorization filters aren't working.?.

Comment: Can you show your Web.config? At least the membership and authentication and connectionStrings and roleManager sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a custom attribute to solve this problem. You can attribute your controller methods as follows:

```
[RequiresRole(Role="Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    int i = 5 + 5;

    return View();
}
```

The code for the attribute is as follows....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class RequiresRoleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string Role { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Role))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No role specified.");
            }

            string redirectOnSuccess = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            string redirectUrl = string.Format("?returnUrl={0}", redirectOnSuccess);
            string loginUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + redirectUrl;

            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
            }
            else
            {
                bool isAuthorised = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(this.Role);
                if (!isAuthorised)
                {                        
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
                }                
            }  
        }      
    }
}
```